# I want to integrate select count(*) and distinct query to my sql command which include group by and where condition?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I want to integrate `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` to my sql code but I'm getting error.

[An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'count(distinct SONG_ID)'.]

I'm using MS Access database in my c# code.
Here is my sql code;

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SONG_ID),CLIENT_ID 
FROM [ExhibitA-input] 
WHERE PLAY_TS BETWEEN DateValue('10.08.2016') AND DateValue('11.08.2016') 
GROUP BY CLIENT_ID;
```

I know that it must be `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` query but I could not find how I will integrate that with my code.

Comment: whats the exact error you get, edit your post accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an inline view.

```
SELECT COUNT(a.SONG_ID),a.CLIENT_ID 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SONG_ID, CLIENT_ID FROM [ExhibitA-input]
      WHERE PLAY_TS BETWEEN DateValue('10.08.2016') AND DateValue('11.08.2016')) AS a
GROUP BY a.CLIENT_ID;
```

Comment: It works fine thanks :) and I tried to add that code,                                             
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (your code + ORDER BY a.CLIENT_ID DESC) but it's not worked :/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about access, but in generell you can try something like

```
select count (song_id), client_id from 
(SELECT distinct SONG_ID ,CLIENT_ID 
FROM [ExhibitA-input] 
WHERE PLAY_TS BETWEEN DateValue('10.08.2016') AND DateValue('11.08.2016') 
 ) e GROUP BY CLIENT_ID ;
```

Comment: Maybe it is special with Access, in SQL it will work.

Comment: Yeah, because of that. Thanks:)